# Re-prompting the user endlessly until the response is correct

Tags: python

Please take a look at my code. I want the program to continuously re-prompt the user while they enter anything other than a positive integer between 1 and 8. I am mainly concerned about non-integer inputs, as negative values and those larger than 8 I can catch.

I have semi-successfully implemented the try-except blocks, but only semi. I think the problem is that I do not fully understand how they work yet...

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("Pyramid's height between 1 and 8: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Must be a number between 1 and 8!")
        continue
    else:
        break
if n >= 1 and n <= 8:
    mario()
else:
    n = int(input("Must be between 1 and 8: "))
```

If the user enters a non-integer right off the bat, the exception catches it:

```
Pyramid's height between 1 and 8: ef
Must be a number between 1 and 8!
Pyramid's height between 1 and 8: 45
Must be between 1 and 8:
```

etc.
But if it happens later down the line:

```
Pyramid's height between 1 and 8: 16
Must be between 1 and 8: efs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pattern4.py", line 23, in <module>
    n = int(input("\nMust be between 1 and 8: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'efs')
```

, then it is already out of the try-except loop and the program is crashing, instead of re-prompting.

Comment: every `int(input())` has to be in (own) `try/except`. And your second `int(input())` is not in `try/except` so you get error.

Comment: @furas is right, just add a similar try and except block for your second input() as well, and the exception will be caught. Right now you're not catching the exception, that's why the program just stops and prints the exception for you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I got it - just needed to include the condition of "n being not larger than 8" into the exception handling blocks rather than outside of them, and that re-prompts if false and starts (and ends) the program if true. Seems to be working like a clock now.

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("Pyramid's height between 1 and 8: "))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        if n >= 1 and n <= 8:
            mario()
            break
```